# laravel pass data, the third argument of the value to evaluate, in the form of an array

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $deptID = Pegawai::where('defaultdeptid', Auth::user()->depid)->get();
    foreach($deptID as $item){
        $result = $item->defaultdeptid;
        // dd($result);
    }
    $iclock = Iclock::where('DeptID', $result)->get();

    $test1 = ($iclock[0]->SN);
    $test2 = ($iclock[1]->SN);
    
    $transaksi = Checkinout::whereIn('SN', [$test1, $test2])->get();
    return view('adminopd.presensi.transaksi.index', compact('transaksi'));
```

I want to ask, how to use whereIn without me having to define index, so I want to pass "Checkinout" if "SN" equals "SN" of "Iclock" and it can be an array or not just one. I'm new to using laravel buddy

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by that index?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I have found a solution, thank you